# How to generated Dynamic Report in java.where to find tutorial clearly

Tags: java, swing, dynamic-reports

I work with Netbeans and add jar files from (dynamicreports-3.2.1\dist(all files)) .
How to Generate Dynamic Report in jbutton.A

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    StyleBuilder boldStyle  = stl.style().bold();

  StyleBuilder boldCenteredStyle = stl.style(boldStyle).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

  StyleBuilder columnTitleStyle  = stl.style(boldCenteredStyle)

                                      .setBorder(stl.pen1Point())

                                      .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);





  TextColumnBuilder<String>     itemColumn      = col.column("Item",       "item",      type.stringType());

  TextColumnBuilder<Integer>    quantityColumn  = col.column("Quantity",   "quantity",  type.integerType());

  TextColumnBuilder<BigDecimal> unitPriceColumn = col.column("Unit price", "unitprice", type.bigDecimalType());

  //price = unitPrice * quantity

  TextColumnBuilder<BigDecimal> priceColumn     = unitPriceColumn.multiply(quantityColumn).setTitle("Price");

  PercentageColumnBuilder       pricePercColumn = col.percentageColumn("Price %", priceColumn);

  TextColumnBuilder<Integer>    rowNumberColumn = col.reportRowNumberColumn("No.")

                                                      //sets the fixed width of a column, width = 2 * character width

                                                     .setFixedColumns(2)

                                                     .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

  try {      

     report()//create new report design

       .setColumnTitleStyle(columnTitleStyle)

       .highlightDetailEvenRows()

       .columns(//add columns

        rowNumberColumn, itemColumn, quantityColumn, unitPriceColumn, priceColumn, pricePercColumn)

       .title(cmp.text("Getting started").setStyle(boldCenteredStyle))//shows report title

       .pageFooter(cmp.pageXofY().setStyle(boldCenteredStyle))//shows number of page at page footer

       .setDataSource(createDataSource())

       .show();//create and show report
} catch (DRException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();



}
}
```

//createDataSource
    private DRDataSource createDataSource() {

```
  DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("item", "quantity", "unitprice");

  dataSource.add("Notebook", 1, new BigDecimal(500));

  dataSource.add("DVD", 5, new BigDecimal(30));

  dataSource.add("DVD", 1, new BigDecimal(28));
  dataSource.add("DVD", 5, new BigDecimal(32));

  dataSource.add("Book", 3, new BigDecimal(11));
  dataSource.add("Book", 1, new BigDecimal(15));

  dataSource.add("Book", 5, new BigDecimal(10));

  dataSource.add("Book", 8, new BigDecimal(9));

  return dataSource;
```

}

RunTimeError:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;

Comment: Check your classpath. Obviously a jar is missing

Comment: Thank you for helped.Add a jar(jasperreports-0.6.3.jar,common-lang3.jar) .then display Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.dynamicreports.report.datasource.DRDataSource cannot be cast to java.util.Collection

Comment: `.setDataSource((Collection<?>) createDataSource())` Look at the [javadoc](http://apidocs.dynamicreports.org/net/sf/dynamicreports/report/datasource/DRDataSource.html) for `DRDataSource` and see if it implements `Collection` ;-)